# Trouble grabbing data from a webpage located within comment

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've written a script in python to get some data from a website. It seems I did it the right way. However, when I print the data I get an error `list index out of range`. The data are within comment. So in my script I tried to use the python's built-in comment processing method. Could anybody point me out where I'm going wrong?

Link to the website: [website_link](https://www.edmunds.com/ford/escape/2017/cost-to-own/?zip=43215)

Script I've tried so far with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

res = requests.get("replace_with_the_above_link")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
for comment in soup.find_all(string=lambda text:isinstance(text,Comment)):
    sauce = BeautifulSoup(comment, 'lxml')
    items = sauce.select("#tco_detail_data")[0]
    data = ' '.join([' '.join(item.text.split()) for item in items.select("li")])
    print(data)
```

This is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\new_line_one.py", line 8, in <module>
    items = sauce.select("#tco_detail_data")[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Please click on the below link to see which portion of data I would like to grab: [Expected_output_link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nrf8cr5cjxli3zx/Untitled.jpg?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the comments contain html with a "#tco_detail_data" tag, so `select` returns an empty list, which raises an `IndexError` when you try to select the first item.

However, you can find the data in a "ul#tco_detail_data" tag.

```
res = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
data = soup.select_one("#tco_detail_data")

print(data)
```

If you want `data` in a list,

```
data = [list(item.stripped_strings) for item in data.select("ul")]
```

If you prefer a string,

```
data = '\n'.join([item.get_text(' ', strip=True) for item in data.select("ul")])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effective solution. Turn out that I was trying with the wrong url. Forgot to add this portion `?zip=43215`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to help! Updated my code to produce a list, i thought it could be useful.